# An "Average theorem for integrals"

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm having trouble with this problem.
Let $f\in\mathfrak{L}_1(X,S,\mu)$ such that exists $k\geq0$ that satisfies; for all $E\in S$ with $0<\mu(E)<\infty,$ $$\frac{|\int_{E}f \, d\mu|}{\mu(E)}\leq k$$ then $|f|\leq k$ almost everywhere.

I have a hint of proving that for any $\alpha >0 $ the set $\{x \in X | |f(x)| > \alpha \}$ has finite measure. If we assume that is true I think the way to go is define $E=\{x\in X| |f(x)|>k\}$ then $\int_E|f|d\mu > \int_Ekd\mu = k\mu(E)$
and from here I don't know where to go. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: This a (special case of a) theorem in the first chapter of Rudin's RCA.

Comment: If  you assume $\mu(E_>0$, then you have that $k\mu(E)<\int_E|f|\leq k\mu(E)$ which is not possiblel hence $\mu(E)=0$

Comment: Imagine the set $f > k$ had positive (potentially infinite) measure. Take a finite part of that set. Does it satisfy the hypothesis?

Comment: @Mittens How can I get the $\int_E |f| \leq k\mu(E)$ inequiality?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes it is the same question but the answer is not really clear

Comment: @IñakiMendieta: that is the assumption made when $\mu(E)>0$ (with $|f|$ in place of $f$ so that $|\int_E|f||=\int_E|f|$